# cyclic sum of primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Suppose $p,q$ and $r$ are primes such that $pq+qr+rp-p-q-r=357$. If $p<q<r$, find the sum of all possible value of $r$.

I can't identify the kernel of the problem, can anyone give me a hint, thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

The way, I solved this, there is no special kernel or neat trick to identify. From
$$357=pq+qr+rp-p-q-r=p(q-1)+q(r-1)+r(p-1)$$
it is obvious, that $p,q,r$ can not become too big. Technically, you could even try all combinations by hand. However, some simple observations can indeed be helpful to reduce the number of cases sharply. I wrote them  down as **hints**:

1. Consider parity to determine the value of $p$.
2. Simplify the expression to obtain an upper bound for $q$.
3. Calculate modulo $q+1$.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

$$(p-1)(q-1)(r-1)=pqr-(pq+qr+rp)+p+q+r-1=pqr-1-(357)$$

$$(p-1)(q-1)(r-1)=pqr-358$$

If $p,q,r$ are all odd, the LHS is even and the RHS is odd which is impossible.

So, at least one of  $p,q,r$ must be even $\implies p=2$

So, the problem reduces to $(q-1)(r-1)=2qr-358$

$\implies (q+1)(r+1)=360<19^2$

$\implies 3\le q<19$ and $r+1$ must be even